# Custom background colors for NSTableCellView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I am trying to create a custom NSTableCellView. I subclassed NSTableCellView and I need to have a custom background color and highlight/selection color. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the background as well as the selection is handled by the `NSTableRowView` view. It CAN (partly) be overwritten by the cell but that's not how it should be at all.

Implement a custom rowview and return that for use behind the row you need to draw

```
@interface MyRowView : NSTableRowView
```

there you have:

- drawBackgroundInRect:
- drawDraggingDestinationFeedbackInRect:
- drawSelectionInRect:
- drawSeparatorInRect:

e.g.

```
@implementation MyRowView

- (void)drawSelectionInRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
        [currentFill fillRect:dirtyRect inContext:[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]graphicsPort]];
}

@end
```

SRC: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableRowView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: the example uses CPTFill to draw a fill btw

Comment: the OP asked for NSTableCellView

Comment: yes and I said: "the background as well as the selection is handled by the NSTableRowView view. It CAN (partly) be overwritten by the cell but that's not how it should be at all."

Comment: it shouldn't / can't easily be done in a tablecellView -- thats what a row view IS MADE FOR :)